# ¿Cómo extraer el mes de una columna de tipo date en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo la tabla anuncio_detalle de la siguiente forma.

```
    Columna    |          Tipo          | Modificadores
---------------+------------------------+---------------
 id_anuncio    | character varying(50)  |
 latitud       | numeric                |
 longitud      | numeric                |
 fecha_entrega | date                   |
 hora_entrega  | time without time zone |
 estado        | boolean                |
```

La columna `fecha_entrega` es de tipo date por lo que tiene el formato `AAAA-MM-DD`, ¿cómo le puedo extraer el **mes** o el **día**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM fecha_entrega) as mes from anuncio_detalle
```

Ahi puedes cambiar "MONTH" por "DAY" o "YEAR" pero te lo dará en entero, es decir si el mes es abril te tirará un "4"

Answer (score 1):

Para ellos puedes usar `to_char`  que es una función predeterminada de PostreSQL.

ejemplo:

```
SELECT to_char(fecha_entrega, 'MM') FROM anuncio_detalle
```

En la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html) de PostgreSQL esta mas especificado cada opcion para cada tipo de columna soportable.

Answer (score 0):

Hola también si quieres  usar las fechas en el idioma local tienes que poner `to_char(ingresos.fechaguia, 'TMMonth')`
y si los deseas en ingles
`to_char(ingresos.fechaguia, 'MONTH')`